# UIView as leftCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to add a UIView as the leftCalloutAccessoryView of a MapKitAnnotation but the textlabel I add to the UIView is not being shown and I don't understand why?

```
let orderInfoView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, annotationView!.frame.size.height))
orderInfoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10))
textLabel.text = "Foobar"
textLabel.textAlignment = .Center

orderInfoView.addSubview(textLabel)

annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = orderInfoView
```

**[UPDATE]**

This was the piece of code which broke it, changing it to a numerical constant made it work.

```
annotationView!.frame.size.height
```